# PUT Request via CURL

Tags: php, curl, put

I'm trying to make an CURL PUT REQUEST, my code looks like:

```
public function assignProfile($token, $organizationId, $profileId)
    {
        //define enviroment and path
        $host = enviroment;
        $path = "/admin/organizations/".$organizationId."/users";       

        $data_string = '["'.$profileId.'"]';        

        // set up the curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host.$path);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$token.'',      
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)                                                                       
        ));

        echo "<br>OK<br>";
        // execute the request      
        $output = curl_exec($ch);       

        // return ID for a new case
        $output = json_decode($output);                 
        var_dump($output);
    }
```

Each part looks correct, when I var_dump `$path`, `$host`, even `$data_string` looks correct. However `var_dump()` at the end throw just `NULL`

I expect I'm doing something wrong or missing something really important.
May I ask you for some advise?

Thanks

EDIT:
What i do with it:

```
// define 
define("Audavin","here is some uniqe ID");
.
.
.
$Users = new Users;
// this return Auth token ( I verify this work with echo )
$token = $Users->authorization();  
// Calling method mentioned above
$Users->assignProfile($token,"here is org id", Audavin);
```

Comment: What's the content of `$output = curl_exec($ch);` ? also,  add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Hey @PedroLobito,  I add error reporting and display error on top of my file, unfortunately it didn't  display any aditional errors. about how i'm calling this method  I edit my question. 
About content I'm not sure you  mean :(

Comment: Do a `echo` **immediately** after `$output = curl_exec($ch); ` what does it show?

Comment: it echo just blanked string if I dump it it say string(""), it definitly looks like I'm getting no response from server

Comment: good! you know where the problem really is, start debugging from there, post any updates after

Answer (score 0):

1. I would start by making sure the URL you're making the request to actually works and returns a valid response, you can do so by using a simple REST client (like POSTMAN chrome extension for example)
2. If you do get a response back, try and see if it's indeed a valid JSON, if not, that could be why you're not getting anything back from json_decode (more on return values here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
3. Finally, It is suggested you add **curl_close($ch)** to the end of your code to make sure your release the curl handle.